# Template functions : mixing pass-by-copy & pass-by-reference

Tags: c++, templates, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have a template function that's in charge of writing a template value to a stream. It looks like this :

```
template < typename T >
void Write( T value, std::ostream& stream, endianness_t endian );
```

I have implemented the versions for basic types : int, uint, float, etc.
Now, if I want to write a more complex structure, say, a std::string, that I declared like this :

```
template<>
inline void Write( const std::string& value, std::ostream& stream, endianness_t endian ) { // Notice the reference
...
}
```

I can't call it without calling explicitly calling the "pass-by-reference" version :

```
Write( strValue, stream, LITTLE_ENDIAN ); // error : tries to call Write<std::string>, undefined
Write< const std::string& >( strValue, stream, LITTLE_ENDIAN ); // OK, Write<const std::string&> is properly defined
```

The problem being that, it's too verbose for what I want to do.

My question then : how can I make the compiler guess that the version I want used is the "pass-by-reference" one ?

Do I have to change my template function to take const references ? If so, can I specialize if to use "pass-by-copy" for primitive types ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should prefer overloads to template specialization, and doing this solves your problem I think:

```
inline void Write( const std::string& value, std::ostream& stream, endianness_t endian ) {
    // ...
}
```

I also recommend going back and changing all your specializations that you mentioned for `int` and stuff to overloads instead.

Comment: Bonus question : is there a risk that, if I define Write(int64) and Write(int32) in that order, Write(int64) will be used when I pass a 32 bit int ?

Comment: @Takhiarel The normal rules for overloading apply. If you pass a 32 bit `int`, the overload which requires the least conversions will be selected (i.e. the 32-bit overload if there is one).

Answer (score 4):

Do not provide overloads for every possible type you want to use. This breaks the logic of using generic code in the first place. That been said, the need to provide a specialization for every type maybe points out that this was not the most successfull application of templates, not to mention that messing around with function template specialization is not the prettiest choice [as Sutter says](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Since you need a logic separation between mutually exclusive types (built ins and non built ins) here's an alternative :

```
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if< std::is_fundamental<T>::value >::type foo_func(T arg)
{
    std::cout << "Call for built in types" << std::endl;
}
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if< !std::is_fundamental<T>::value >::type foo_func(T  const &arg)
{
    std::cout << "Call for non built in types" << std::endl;
}
```

To explain the code here what happens:

1) std::is_fundamental will return false or true at compile time depending on whether T is user defined or a built in type respectively.

2) std::enable_if will "allow" the declaration of the function template for **true** in the first case and **false** in the second, so no resolution problems can happen.

3) so when calling foo_func for built in types, the first version will be used and T (int, float and so on) is passed by value (which is faster for built ins) and ... well you can imaging what happens in the other case.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the generic template to pass by const ref:

```
template < typename T >
void Write( const T& value, std::ostream& stream, endianness_t endian );
```

Comment: It might be a solution, but isnt there a performance penalty for primitive types in doing so ?

Comment: @Takhiarel: That's a good question.  I'm assuming that the `Write` function is small and simple enough that it'll be be auto-inlined.  The compiler will then make the indirection disappear.